# PHP For/Foreach passed by reference at the end of for end the reference.

Tags: php

In php you can pass the row by reference by adding & to the data.

```
foreach($data as $key => &$row) {
}
```

At the end of the for/foreach is it possible to end the reference, so if $row is called again later, it does not overwrite the last variable in $data?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php

Comment: And there is an example of just this: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thank you for posting that Rizier, I tried that and it still unsets the last.  In a foreach it does not work that way.

Comment: Provide us a little [mcve] and show what input you have, what output you get and what output you expect.